# Why do I have spin splitting at 5 and 7 at the quantum hall effect?

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

I just learned something about the quantum hall effect, and was wondering about the spin splitting at a filling factor of 5 and 7, i.e. I have nearly equal sized plateaus for the filling factor of 2, 3 and 4, but I have only a small plateau at 5, and no plateau at 7. I asked my teacher, but he could not give me an explanation for this, he only could tell me that is has something to do with spin splitting. So, why do I get these "small" plateaus, and why is there a spin splitting?